# updating timestamp php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, insert-update

I have a sample database of students in a class with their id(UNIQUE), name,gender, birhdate, marks etc.

What i intend to do is :

1. if the student has not entered his data, it should insert the data.
2. if the student is using for the second time, the time should update. 
   i used the code below but its not working .

Thanks!!

```
// open connection 
      $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 
      // select database 
      mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO UserData VALUES ('$id','$name','$gender','$email','$birthday','Marks','NOW()')");
      mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: "if the student has not entered his data, it should insert the data." What do you mean by that?`How to insert data which is not known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using an ORM like [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) which allows you to write code like this:

```
$user = UserQuery::create()->findPK($id);
if(!$user) {
  $user = new User();
  $user->setId($id);
}
$user->setName($name);
$user->setGender($gender);
$user->setEmail($email);
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I will strongly suggest that you use the field names in the query:

```
INSERT INTO UserData (`id`, `name`, `gender`, `email`, `bday`, `marks`, `time`)
VALUES ('$id','$name','$gender','$email','$birthday', $marks, NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `time` = NOW()
```

I am assuming that you have a unique index on `id` (or it is the primary key). Also, please replace the column names in the query above with the actual column names as per your schema.

For more details, see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

If you can post your table schema, then I can provide the exact query that you need to use.

Comment: Never seen this- pretty cool. I have doubts that updating the time is really all they want to do.

Comment: Yeah, updating just the time does not make much sense.  Anyway, the query can be extended to update multiple columns. Also, if all columns need to be updated, then `REPLACE` can be used instead of `INSERT` in his original query.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` != `UPDATE`

If you want to update an existing record you need to write an `UPDATE` query. You could use a `REPLACE` query, but it will overwrite the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes enclosing `NOW()`
so instead of `'NOW()'` it should be just `NOW()`, as it is a MYSQL function